# How to destroy widget while preserving the root node to which it was attached?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to destroy a widget but preserve the dom node to which it was attached?  For example I have a div

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
</body>
```

When i attach the widget like this

```
 new someWidget({}, 'app');
```

to this node by Id I get something like

```
<body>
    <div id="app" widgetid="app">
    </div>
</body>
```

Then when i call destroy on the widget like this

```
var mywidget = registry.byId("app");
mywidget.destroy();
```

I end up with

```
<body>
</body>
```

The entire div to which the widget was attached disappears.  But what i really want is to 'detach' then destroy the widget and keep the original div to which it was attached.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this. First is to use a `data-dojo-attach-point` and place the widget node using `domConstruct.place`. This will append the widget node to the target thus making the widget a child of the target node. Later, when you will destroy the widget, the main node in which you placed the widget will not be destroyed.

```
<body>
<div data-dojo-attach-point="app"></div>
</body>


var myWidget= new someWidget();
domConstruct.place(myWidget.domNode, this.app);
```

Second is to use `myWidget.destroy(true)`. See the [__WidgetBase destroy()](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase#1_10dijit__WidgetBase_destroy) documentation here. The argument passed refers to the `preserveDom` attribute and is false by default. It it is true, then the original DOM structure will be preserved. Quoting from the source page:

> If true, this method will leave the original DOM structure alone. Note: This will not yet work with _TemplatedMixin widgets